# Fortran: Passing in a hardcoded value to a function accepting a real(16) doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

Relevant code:

```
Parts(3, indexcount) = push(pi/2, 0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0, Parts(1, indexcount),Parts(2, indexcount), 0.01d0, 20000.0d0)

 real(16) function push(phaseinit, yinit, pxinit, pyinit, a0, R, dt, Time_total)
implicit none
real(16) :: phaseinit, yinit, pxinit, pyinit, gammamax, I0, R_star, k_ratio, Vph

etc...
```

When compiling:

```
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'yinit' at (1); passed REAL(8) to REAL(16)
```

I tried to find online resources detailing how exactly to properly initialize a numerical value for a `real(16)`, but I couldn't find anything. This seemingly allows me to initialize `real(8)`, but I don't know what the corresponding procedure is for `real(16)`.

Comment: That is, `0._16` is a real literal constant of kind 16.  Other questions, answers, comments will address the fact that you should be careful assuming that 16.

Comment: Almost any Fortran related source address this issue. You can search online for _fortran literal kind parameter_ .

Comment: My preference would be to use the real intrinsic, although this does not work with all values. real(0,16), real(20000.0d0,16) and real(1,16)/100 all work, but real(0.01d0,16) does not.  For me, it provides some documentation of what is being required.